# Is there a way to prevent data overwrite error and leave mapping table cell blank?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, overwrite

[sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TVm5uBwDH-rczG-yan9NUL7oa_PtsmnSD0JQuAjBpkU/edit) Is there a way to code it so I can have blanks in my mapping table without.
the formula failing in my budget sheet?

I want it to be able to recognize when the category is Travel, it is Variable and Discretionary. However, I want to leave Travel Blank in the Mapping Table because I don’t want to have to specify each exact transaction that would be categorized as Travel; rather, I’d like it to autofill based on the general Travel Category.

The following formulas have worked, but return ERROR messages because it says it would overwrite data when I type in a specific transaction and then attempt to categorize it as Travel in my Budget sheet.

These all fail when I try to enter data into the Category Column when the Transaction Column is blank in my Mapping Table.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(BudgetTransaction, {RefTrans, RefCategory}, 2, FALSE), "")

=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(BudgetTransaction & BudgetCategory, {RefTrans & RefCategory, RefFreq}, 2, FALSE), ""))

=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(BudgetTransaction<>"", IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(BudgetTransaction, RefTrans, 0)), VLOOKUP(BudgetTransaction, {RefTrans, RefCategory}, 2, FALSE), ""), ""), ""))

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((BudgetTransaction<>"")*(NOT(ISBLANK(BudgetTransaction)))*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(BudgetTransaction, RefTrans, 0))), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(BudgetTransaction, {RefTrans, RefCategory}, 2, FALSE), ""), ""))
```

you can see the [google_sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TVm5uBwDH-rczG-yan9NUL7oa_PtsmnSD0JQuAjBpkU/edit)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TVm5uBwDH-rczG-yan9NUL7oa_PtsmnSD0JQuAjBpkU/edit

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply `INDEX-MATCH` to the whole column like this. Use [`XLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12405947?hl=en) or [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) instead:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C="",,VLOOKUP(C2:C,'Mapping Table'!B2:C,2,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Although, there still seems to be a REF ERROR message when I input an existing category with a transaction that isn’t specifically listed on the mapping table. Is there an alternative/should I abandon the mapping table entirely?

Comment: a cell must either have a manually entered result or a result generated by a formula. It cannot have both.